# Element with locator not found in page pop up

Tags: selenium, robotframework, element

The Selenium is not found this element:

```
<div class="import-file">
     <input name="ctl00$MainContent$btnAttachment" type="button" id="MainContent_btnAttachment" class="button-norl img-upload-text b" value="แนบไฟล์">
     <input type="file" name="ctl00$MainContent$fuAttachment" id="MainContent_fuAttachment" onchange="akUploadfile('[id$=fuAttachment]',$('[id$=hdnFileType1]').val());">
</div>
```

My robot code:

```
VA_M03_0108
[Tags]  Carregis
Login.Input user name   ${USER}         ${PASS}
SendCar
Click Element       id=ContentPlaceHolder1_rpt_search_lblCarReceiveDoc_0
Sleep  2s
Wait Until Element Is Visible     id=UpdatePanel1         timeout=20s
Choose File        id=MainContent_fuAttachment     ${CURDIR}/ใบรับรถ.jpg
```

The robot response:

```
Element 'id=MainContent_fuAttachment' not visible after 20 seconds.
```

Anyone, please help me.
This is the UI: https://www.sendspace.com/file/kqerdt

Comment: Do you see the element in the screenshot? Have you tried `Wait Until Page Contains`, and does it succeeds?

Comment: It doesn't succeed.

Comment: Is this code example correct? `Wait Until ...` and `Choose File` do not refer to the same id.

Comment: Because the selenium connot find id=MainContent_fuAttachment then I use id=UpdatePanel1 for Wait Until.... to prove that selenium can find some element in this pop up.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/kqerdt link is dead

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're checking for an element within a POP-UP windows, first you have to select the newly popped-up window with "Select window".
After this is covered, try checking if the page contains the element.
If it does, try checking for any visibility attribute that could prevent it from being displayed on the screen.
A transparent object sitting on top of the searched object could also make the visibility check fail (imho visibility checks on Robotframework are a really obscure matter).

For debugging, add a capture page screen shot just after the sleep and check yourself visually for the state in which the page finds itself at that moment.

Comment: Could you complete the sentence there please.